# Site URL needs index.php

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I was asked to fix a problem on a website.

Here's the problem, the site has this url:

```
www.hosting.com/~website/
```

When links are click/hovered, it shows something like:

```
www.hosting.com/~website/link.html
```

But gives an error when clicked/loaded.
But when you add index.php after ~website/, it loads the correct page.
Like

```
www.hosting.com/~website/index.php/link.html
```

I'm currently trying to mess up the .htaccess to fix this but to no avail.
Anyone who can help me figure out this problem?

The site is running on Joomla.

Comment: http://www.yireo.com/tutorials/joomla/joomla-administration/1338-get-rid-of-indexphp-in-your-joomla-urls

Comment: go to the Global Configuration and mess around with the option on the right hand side regarding SEF etc

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the rewrite base to /~website/ see http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=697628#p2775626

Comment: I did something like this but weren't able to have it work. Then after a while I modified it and added index.php so it becomes /~website/index.php and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent! Mind accepting this as the correct answer and posting any notes as needed to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

try setting rewrite base to "/" in .htaccess

Comment: Why is that expected to improve things?